# alternative to recover deleted esc key in vimrc file?

Tags: vim

I tried to map shift + p key to the esc key but accidently changed esc key to another.

so currently I am not able to get out of insert mode after changing .vimrc file.

I already used karabiner for mac (3rd praty), but it does not working since the precedence of vimrc is higher than that.

any alternatives..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand the problem.

If there's an erroneous mapping in your .vimrc, you can use any other text editor to fix it.

Or you can use `vim -u NONE` to start vim without reading your .vimrc.

In a pinch, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> may get you out of insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + [ sends the escape key command.

I need to use that on an iPad keyboard with no escape key.

Comment: That probably won't help you if you've remapped `ESC` inside vim.